# Using TFS as a build server and Git as main Repo

Tags: git, version-control, tfs, build, continuous-integration

I have a private `Git` repo with my code.
I also have a server with `Tfs 2013 express.

I want my TFS server to fetch the code from my private Git repo and build it daily.
Also run unit tests if possible.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish your Git repo into TFS to get it to build it.

http://www.alexandervanwynsberghe.be/moving-existing-git-repository-tfservicetfs-2013/

This walkthough shows how to publish your local Git repo to the server repo.